# Is Ubuntu 18.04 compatible with the new MacBook Pro 13" (with Touch Bar)

Tags: 18.04, macbook

I'd be glad to know if anyone tried installing the new Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro with touch bar.
There were issues with older version (that got partily fixed with this https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7) and I wonder if they got solved.

Thanks,

Barak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The touchbar doesn't work as it is designed to work with OSx. The camera might not be found initially, but there is a fix for it. Everything else works well.

Comment: Thanks! Works out of the box (apart from the camera)? Or does it need driver and further actions like the gist I posted? I also know that in the past there were problems with audio, wifi and such. All gone? And is the knowledge gained from personally installing? Thank you so much and sorry for all the questions

Comment: Thanks or adding more info. I have tried ubunto on many different macs(imacs, macbook pros, macbook air, 2012,2015,2017) (I guess I have a fetish for running ubuntu on macs!  :) and all I can tell you, is that all behave differently with different distros. It all eventually comes to your personal experience. For instance, some find the wifi not working, which can be fixed by installing the bcmwl driver, some find the "fan running like hell" which can be fixed by installing the macfanctld (all available from the ubuntu repository these days).

Comment: Hope everything works out for you and hope you enjoy your new mac!

Answer (score 0):

It might work and if it does probably not as well as on Mac. You might have a better chance of getting it to work through a virtual machine. But if you do try make sure you dual boot and partition your hard drive/ssd.

Comment: I got 16.04 on VM only because of the compatability issues, I'd love to get it going properly with dual booting, though I'm not sure all the driver issues were solved.